# Homeomorphism of $\mathbb{S}^1$ of certain type

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

Suppose $f(z)=z^2\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$, where $a\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $|a|\geq3$.

My idea: Surjectivity is quite evident. But when dealing with injectivity, I have encountered difficulty. In complex analysis, it's well known that if $f'(x_0)\neq 0$, then $f$ is locally conformal at $x_0$. However, we have to deal with the whole $\mathbb{S}^1$ here. I tried to compute directly, but in vain. My teacher gave a hint that argument of principle might be helpful. However, I stil don't know on which area should we use this theorem.

Any solution or hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Show that the argument of $f'/f$ changes by $2\pi$ on the circle if and only if $|a| > 1$  (easy as you have a decomposition in three simple fractions) and then that $f'$ doesn't vanish on the circle if and only if $|a| \le 1$ or $|a| \ge 3$ (quadratic with real discriminant and easy to see that roots have modulus one when discriminant is negative); together these imply result (note that if $|a| < 1$ the argument  changes by $6\pi$ and $f$ is $3$ to $1$ on the circle although  derivative  doesn't  vanish there)