# Analytic Homeomorphism on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

It's a problem from my complex dynamics lesson.

> Prove that $f:\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{T}$ is a homoemorphism iff $\lvert a\rvert\geq 3$,where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle and $$ f(z)=z^2\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$$

This is the third part of a problem,and the first two questions are following:

> (1). Let $R$ be arational map satsfying $R(\mathbb{T})\subset \mathbb{T}$.Prove that $R$ must be the following form
> $$
> R\left( z \right) =e^{i\theta}\prod_{i=1}^d{\frac{z-a_i}{1-\overline{a_i}z}}\qquad where~a_i\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{T}~and~\theta \in R
> $$
> (2).If $\lvert a_i\rvert\leq 1$ for all $1\leq i\leq d$,what is the Julia set of $R$?

I have solved the first two problems. The first mainly utilizes the principle of maximum modulus. The second answer is  $\mathcal{J}(R)=\mathbb{T}$ or Cantor set on $\mathbb{T}$.

I don't know how the third question is related to the first two questions, nor do I know what kind of technology should be used to solve it. Maybe it only needs the method of complex analysis to solve it.

Comment: Same question (without answer but with some hints) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3987338/42969

Comment: $f$ is a rational function carrying $\Bbb T$ to $\Bbb T$. so it must have an expression such as $R$ from part $1$. What are the $a_i$ and $\theta$? What does the Julia set of a homeomorphism look like?